# Get dataType of a particular element in a column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe column where I am getting timestamp, but some of the fields in the column have data stored as a float, which I want to convert to string.

| ID | Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 29163460257 | 1578317069860.0 |
| 29163460210 | 1578317184281 |
| 29163446462 | 1578318141118.0 |
| 69163462276 | 1578317966529.0 |
| 49163462527 | 1578317252416 |
| 89162811628 | 1578317420869.0 |
| 84694509358 | 1490222719481.0 |
| 36660341026 |  |
| 26660291026 |  |
| 66634141026 |  |

I want to convert suppose **1578318141118.0** to **1578318141118**.

I tried many blogs like:

https://datatofish.com/data-type-pandas-dataframe/

https://thispointer.com/how-to-get-check-data-types-of-dataframe-columns-in-python-pandas/

Nothing seems to work.

Can anyone help me with this

Ex:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
.
.
.
df_final.loc[df_final['Timestamp'].dtypes == float, 'TESTING'] = 'CAUGHT'  
df_final.loc[df_final['Timestamp'].dtypes == float, 'TESTING'] = 'NOT AN ISSUE'
```

Or

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
.
.
.
df_final.loc[isinstance(df_final['Timestamp'], float) == True, 'TESTING'] = 'CAUGHT'  
df_final.loc[isinstance(df_final['Timestamp'], float) == False, 'TESTING'] = 'NO NEED'
```

Comment: Just use `.astype(int)` ?   `df_final['Timestamp'] = df_final['Timestamp'].astype(int)`   If you want ultimately convert to string:  `df_final['Timestamp'] = df_final['Timestamp'].astype(int).astype(str)`

Comment: I get below error : ```
df_final['Timestamp'].fillna('NA').astype(str)
df_final['TESTING'] = df_final['last_activation_time'].astype(int).astype(str)
```

ERROR   : Failed to convert Timestamp . = 15 --- <type 'exceptions.ValueError'> --- invalid literal for long() with base 10: ''

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify to int64

```py
df['Timestamp'].dropna().astype('int64')
```

Comment: If I dont wont to drop empty fields then ?

Comment: Same issue even with this : ```
df_final['TESTING'] = df_final['Timestamp'].dropna().astype('int64')
```

ERROR   : Failed to convert Timestamp . = 15 --- <type 'exceptions.ValueError'> --- invalid literal for long() with base 10: ''

Comment: Is uour input data is different in your question to the data you are using in code?

Answer (score 0):

As your `Timestamp` column contains some null / `NaN` values and your ultimate goal is to convert the float number e.g. `1578318141118.0` to `'1578318141118'` in string format, you can do it in 2 steps:

1. Convert the float number to [`nullable integer data type`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html)
2. Then, convert to string format

Code:

```
df_final['Timestamp'] = df_final['Timestamp'].astype('Int64').astype(str)
```

**Input:**

```
text = """
ID,Timestamp
29163460257,1578317069860.0
29163460210,1578317184281
29163446462,1578318141118.0
69163462276,1578317966529.0
49163462527,1578317252416
89162811628,1578317420869.0
84694509358,1490222719481.0
36660341026,
26660291026,
66634141026,
"""

from io import StringIO
df_final = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text))
```

**Output:**

```
print(df_final)

            ID      Timestamp
0  29163460257  1578317069860
1  29163460210  1578317184281
2  29163446462  1578318141118
3  69163462276  1578317966529
4  49163462527  1578317252416
5  89162811628  1578317420869
6  84694509358  1490222719481
7  36660341026           <NA>
8  26660291026           <NA>
9  66634141026           <NA>
```

The float numbers have been converted to integers and further to strings.  Null values have been converted to string `'<NA>'`.

If you want to keep the null values as `NaN`, we can further do:

```
import numpy as np
df_final['Timestamp'] = df_final['Timestamp'].replace('<NA>', np.nan)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_final)

            ID      Timestamp
0  29163460257  1578317069860
1  29163460210  1578317184281
2  29163446462  1578318141118
3  69163462276  1578317966529
4  49163462527  1578317252416
5  89162811628  1578317420869
6  84694509358  1490222719481
7  36660341026            NaN
8  26660291026            NaN
9  66634141026            NaN
```

Or, if you want to keep the null values as blank, we can do:

```
df_final['Timestamp'] = df_final['Timestamp'].replace('<NA>', '')
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_final)

            ID      Timestamp
0  29163460257  1578317069860
1  29163460210  1578317184281
2  29163446462  1578318141118
3  69163462276  1578317966529
4  49163462527  1578317252416
5  89162811628  1578317420869
6  84694509358  1490222719481
7  36660341026               
8  26660291026               
9  66634141026
```